# Ideal way to cancel an executing AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am running remote audio-file-fetching and audio file playback operations in a background thread using `AsyncTask`. A `Cancellable` progress bar is shown for the time the fetch operation runs.

I want to cancel/abort the `AsyncTask` run when the user cancels (decides against) the operation. What is the ideal way to handle such a case?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Just discovered that `AlertDialogs`'s `boolean cancel(...);` I've been using everywhere actually does nothing. Great.
So...

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private volatile boolean running = true;
    private final ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    public MyTask(Context ctx) {
        progressDialog = gimmeOne(ctx);

        progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
        progressDialog.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                // actually could set running = false; right here, but I'll
                // stick to contract.
                cancel(true);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        running = false;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        while (running) {
            // does the hard work
        }
        return null;
    }

    // ...

}
```

Comment: additionally I called the cancel method on the AsyncTask

Comment: instead of making a boolean flag for running , couldn't you remove it and make this  while(!isCanceled())???

Comment: From docs about onCancelled(): "Runs on the UI thread **after** cancel(boolean) is invoked and doInBackground(Object[]) has finished." This 'after' means that setting a flag in onCancelled and checking in doInBackground makes no sense.

Comment: @confucius thats right, but this way background thread doesn't get interrupted, suppose the case when uploading image, the uploading process continues in background and we didn't get onPostExecute called.

Comment: @lopek The suggestion was to use `isCancelled`, which you can call from any thread. The `onCancelled` callback is different.

Comment: @DanHulme I believe I referred to the code snippet provided in the answer, not to the confucius's comment (which is right).

Comment: @lopek I see what you mean now. Yes, you're right that the answer won't work at all.

Comment: I think this accepted answer does not work，keep it accepted is confusing

Comment: Yes, this answer **doesn't work**. In the doInBackground, replace `while(running)` with `while(!isCancelled())` as others have said here in the comments.

Comment: This is answer is not correct....imagine a condition where you are not in a loop , but simply waiting for an http call to finish. At the time it entered running was true ..but once the running became false no effect on waiting and the prcess continues waiting.

Comment: The method you need to implement to be aware of when it is cancelled is ```onCancelled(Void aVoid)```.

Answer (score 76):

**If you're doing computations**:

- You have to check `isCancelled()` periodically.

**If you're doing a HTTP request**:

- Save the instance of your `HttpGet` or `HttpPost` somewhere (eg. a public field).
- After calling `cancel`, call `request.abort()`. This will cause `IOException` be thrown inside your `doInBackground`.

In my case, I had a connector class which I used in various AsyncTasks. To keep it simple, I added a new `abortAllRequests` method to that class and called this method directly after calling `cancel`.

Comment: thank you, it works, but how to avoid the exception in this case?

Comment: You must call `HttpGet.abort()` from a background thread or you'll get a `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

Comment: @wrygiel If you're doing an HTTP request, shouldn't `cancel(true)` interrupt the request? From documentation: `If the task has already started, then the mayInterruptIfRunning parameter determines whether the thread executing this task should be interrupted in an attempt to stop the task.`

Comment: `HttpURLConnection.disconnect();`

Comment: If you have a cpu consuming operation in AsyncTask, so you must call `cancel(true)`. I used it and it works.

Comment: what is `request.abort()`??

Answer (score 20):

The thing is that AsyncTask.cancel() call only calls the onCancel function in your task. This is where you want to handle the cancel request.

Here is a small task I use to trigger an update method

```
private class UpdateTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        private boolean running = true;

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            running = false;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            onUpdate();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
             while(running) {
                 publishProgress();
             }
             return null;
        }
     }
```

Comment: This will work, but logically  when you are waiting for server response, and you just did db operation, then is should reflect correct changes to your activity. I wrote a blog on that, see my answer.

Comment: As mentioned in comments on the accepted answer, there is no need to create your own `running` flag. AsyncTask has an internal flag that is set when the task has been cancelled. Replace `while (running)` with `while (!isCancelled())`.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#isCancelled()  So in this simple case, you don't need `onCancelled()` override.

Answer (score 11):

Simple: don't use an `AsyncTask`. `AsyncTask` is designed for short operations that end quickly (tens of seconds) and therefore do not need to be canceled. "Audio file playback" does not qualify. You don't even need a background thread for ordinary audio file playback.

Comment: are you suggesting we use regular java thread and "abort" the thread run using volatile boolean variable - the conventional Java way?

Comment: I don't know about `volatile` -- I tend to use `java.util.concurrent` objects for that sort of thing.

Comment: No offense Mike, but that's not an acceptable answer. AsyncTask has a cancel method, and it should work. As far as I can tell, it doesn't - but even if I'm doing it wrong, then there should be a right way to cancel a task. The method wouldn't exist otherwise.

And even short tasks may need canceling - I have an Activity where it begins an AsyncTask immediately upon loading, and if the user hits back immediately after opening the task, they'll see a Force Close a second later when the task finishes but no context exists for it to use in its onPostExecute.

Comment: @Klondike: I have no idea who "Mike" is. "but that's not an acceptable answer" -- you are welcome to your opinion. "AsyncTask has a cancel method, and it should work." -- canceling threads in Java has been a problem for ~15 years. It has nothing much to do with Android. With respect to your "Force Close" scenario, that can be solved by a boolean variable, which you test in `onPostExecute()` to see whether you should go ahead with the work.

Comment: Yikes, can't believe I said "Mike" - my apologies on that.

Canceling threads in Java may have been a problem for 15 years, but if it's not reliable there shouldn't be a method in the Android SDK that has a boolean flag that implies the thread will be actively interrupted if it's that non-deterministic. It may as well not be there.

Comment: I realize I'm bringing up an old topic, but I'm using AsyncTask for network calls. There take ~5s to complete, but I'd still like the user to have an option to cancel the non-critical ones if they choose. Are you saying `AsyncTask.cancel()` method is not reliable?

Comment: @Tejaswi Yerukalapudi: It's more that it won't do anything automatically. See the accepted answer on this question.

Comment: You are supposed to check the isCancelled method periodically in your doInBackground on AsyncTask. It's right there in the docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#isCancelled()

Answer (score 4):

The only way to do it is by checking the value of the isCancelled() method and stopping playback when it returns true.

Answer (score 4):

This is how I write my AsyncTask
the key point is add Thread.sleep(1);

```
@Override   protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {

        Log.d(TAG, PRE + "url:" + params[0]);
        Log.d(TAG, PRE + "file name:" + params[1]);
        downloadPath = params[1];

        int returnCode = SUCCESS;
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            File file = new File(params[1]);
            fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();
            InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);

            byte[] data = new byte[10240]; 
            int nFinishSize = 0;
            while( bis.read(data, 0, 10240) != -1){
                fos.write(data, 0, 10240);
                nFinishSize += 10240;
                **Thread.sleep( 1 ); // this make cancel method work**
                this.publishProgress(nFinishSize);
            }              
            data = null;    
            Log.d(TAG, "download ready in"
                  + ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000)
                  + " sec");

        } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, PRE + "Error: " + e);
                returnCode = FAIL;
        } catch (Exception e){
                 e.printStackTrace();           
        } finally{
            try {
                if(fos != null)
                    fos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, PRE + "Error: " + e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return returnCode;
    }
```

Comment: I found that simply calling cancel(true) on the async task and checking isCancelled() periodically does work, but depending on what your task is doing, can take up to 60 seconds before it gets interupted. Adding the Thread.sleep(1) enables it to get interupted immediately. (Async Task goes into a Wait state rather and isn't discarded immediately). Thanks for this.

Answer (score 0):

Our global AsyncTask class variable

```
LongOperation LongOperationOdeme = new LongOperation();
```

And KEYCODE_BACK action which interrupt AsyncTask

```
   @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            LongOperationOdeme.cancel(true);
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like to force interrupt my async tasks with `cancel(true)` unnecessarily because they may have resources to be freed, such as closing sockets or file streams, writing data to the local database etc. On the other hand, I have faced situations in which the async task refuses to finish itself part of the time, for example sometimes when the main activity is being closed and I request the async task to finish from inside the activity's `onPause()` method. So it's not a matter of simply calling `running = false`. I have to go for a mixed solution: both call `running = false`, then giving the async task a few milliseconds to finish, and then call either `cancel(false)` or `cancel(true)`.

```
if (backgroundTask != null) {
    backgroundTask.requestTermination();
    try {
        Thread.sleep((int)(0.5 * 1000));
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (backgroundTask.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED) {
        backgroundTask.cancel(false);
    }
    backgroundTask = null;
}
```

As a side result, after `doInBackground()` finishes, sometimes the `onCancelled()` method is called, and sometimes `onPostExecute()`. But at least the async task termination is guaranteed.

Comment: Look like a race condition.

Answer (score 0):

With reference to Yanchenko's answer on 29 April '10:
Using a 'while(running)' approach is neat when your code under 'doInBackground' has to be executed multiple times during every execution of the AsyncTask. If your code under 'doInBackground' has to be executed only once per execution of the AsyncTask, wrapping all your code under 'doInBackground' in a 'while(running)' loop will not stop the background code (background thread) from running when the AsyncTask itself is cancelled, because the 'while(running)' condition will only be evaluated once all the code inside the while loop has been executed at least once. You should thus either 
(a.) break up your code under 'doInBackground' into multiple 'while(running)' blocks or 
(b.) perform numerous 'isCancelled' checks throughout your 'doInBackground' code, as explained under "Cancelling a task" at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html.

For option (a.) one can thus modify Yanchenko's answer as follows:

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

private volatile boolean running = true;

//...

@Override
protected void onCancelled() {
    running = false;
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

    // does the hard work

    while (running) {
        // part 1 of the hard work
    }

    while (running) {
        // part 2 of the hard work
    }

    // ...

    while (running) {
        // part x of the hard work
    }
    return null;
}

// ...
```

For option (b.) your code in 'doInBackground' will look something like this:

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

//...

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

    // part 1 of the hard work
    // ...
    if (isCancelled()) {return null;}

    // part 2 of the hard work
    // ...
    if (isCancelled()) {return null;}

    // ...

    // part x of the hard work
    // ...
    if (isCancelled()) {return null;}
}

// ...
```