# Using AsyncTask to download, how to cancel

Tags: android, multithreading

I use AsyncTask to download a file from the Internet, but when I call cancel to cancel the AsyncTask, the thread does not stop downloading. And when I do a test, I find when finishing the Activity, Android will not stop the thread in the Activity. So how can I stop downloading the file? Thanks!

Comment: How are you calling `AsyncTask.cancel`? Do you pass true for the `mayInterruptIfRunning` parameter?

Comment: similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735102/ideal-way-to-cancel-an-executing-asynctask

Comment: i have called AsyncTask.cancel(true),and the doInBackground() will not return a value,but i have found that the doInBackground() is still running with some log test.

Comment: Would you mind sharing your solution? Thanks!

Comment: i make a flag,when the flag is true continue to download,when calling AsyncTask.cancel,set the flag to false,then the thread will be over

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Cancel Async Task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039158/android-cancel-async-task)