# Android: Cancel Async Task

Tags: android, asynchronous, task, back

I use an async task to upload an image and get some results.

While uploading the image I see a progress dialog, written in onPreExecute() method like this:

```
    protected void onPreExecute() { 
         uploadingDialog = new ProgressDialog(MyActivity.this); 
         uploadingDialog.setMessage("uploading"); 
         uploadingDialog.setCancelable(true);
         uploadingDialog.show();
    }
```

Ok when I press the back button, obviously the dialog disappears because of the setCancelable(true).

But (obviously) the async task doesn't stop.

So how can I fix this? I want to cancel both dialog and async task when I press the back button. Any ideas?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**FOUND THE SOLUTION**:
I added an action listener before uploadingDialog.show() like this:

```
    uploadingDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener(){
          public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
              myTask.cancel(true);
              //finish();
          }
    });
```

That way when I press the back button, the above OnCancelListener cancels both dialog and task. Also you can add finish() if you want to finish the whole activity on back pressed. Remember to declare your async task as a variable like this:

```
    MyAsyncTask myTask=null;
```

and execute your async task like this:

```
    myTask = new MyAsyncTask();
    myTask.execute();
```

Comment: What is the difference between your solution and solution posted by me above for adding action listener?

Comment: You don't have to set the cancel listener so overtly before showing the dialog, there's a `show` method which accepts a cancel listener as one of its parameters.

Comment: Should the onPostExecute dismiss the dialog under normal operation?

Answer (score 111):

From SDK:

> Cancelling a task
>
> A task can be cancelled at any time by invoking cancel(boolean). 
>   Invoking this method will cause subsequent calls to isCancelled() 
>   to return true. 
>  
>   After invoking this method, onCancelled(Object), instead of 
>   onPostExecute(Object) will be invoked after doInBackground(Object[]) returns. 
>   To ensure that a task is cancelled as quickly as possible, 
>   you should always check the return value of isCancelled() periodically from 
>   doInBackground(Object[]), if possible (inside a loop for instance.)

So your code is right for dialog listener:

```
uploadingDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
        myTask.cancel(true);
        //finish();
    }
});
```

Now, as I have mentioned earlier from SDK, you have to check whether the task is cancelled or not, for that you have to check **isCancelled()** inside the onPreExecute() method.

For example:

```
if (isCancelled()) 
    break;
else
{
   // do your work here
}
```

Comment: Yes I agree with you, but the thing is that I don't use a loop on my doInBackground. I just use some commands to upload an image via ftp. So I'm wondering, does it matter to check whether the task is cancelled or not before I send the image, like you said?

Comment: @mole363, you have to just check whether the task is cancelled or not by using isCancelled() inside the doInBackground method.

Comment: This will not cancel a network operation as there is no loop involved.

Comment: "have to check isCancelled() inside the onPreExecute() method."...can you please explain this?As far as doc: "Calling this method will result in onCancelled(Object) being invoked on the UI thread after doInBackground(Object[]) returns. Calling this method guarantees that onPostExecute(Object) is never invoked. After invoking this method, you should check the value returned by isCancelled() periodically from doInBackground(Object[]) to finish the task as early as possible."

Comment: That means onCancelled() callback will be invoked once the user calls mytask.cancel(true); on the asynctask

Answer (score 12):

I spent a while figuring this out, all I wanted was a simple example of how to do it, so I thought I'd post how I did it. This is some code that updates a library and has a progress dialog showing how many books have been updated and cancels when a user dismisses the dialog:

```
private class UpdateLibrary extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Boolean>{
    private ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(Library.this);
    private int total = Library.instance.appState.getAvailableText().length;
    private int count = 0;

    //Used as handler to cancel task if back button is pressed
    private AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Boolean> updateTask = null;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        updateTask = this;
        dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        dialog.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {               
            @Override
            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                updateTask.cancel(true);
            }
        });
        dialog.setMessage("Updating Library...");
        dialog.setMax(total);
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < appState.getAvailableText().length;i++){
                if(isCancelled()){
                    break;
                }
                //Do your updating stuff here
            }
        }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress){
        count += progress[0];
        dialog.setProgress(count);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean finished){
        dialog.dismiss();
        if (finished)
            DialogHelper.showMessage(Str.TEXT_UPDATELIBRARY, Str.TEXT_UPDATECOMPLETED, Library.instance);
        else 
            DialogHelper.showMessage(Str.TEXT_UPDATELIBRARY,Str.TEXT_NOUPDATE , Library.instance);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

create some member variables in your activity like

```
YourAsyncTask mTask;
Dialog mDialog;
```

use these for your dialog and task;

in onPause()  simply call

```
if(mTask!=null) mTask.cancel(); 
if(mDialog!=null) mDialog.dismiss();
```

Answer (score 7):

I would like to improve the code. When you canel the `aSyncTask` the `onCancelled()` (callback method of `aSyncTask`) gets automatically called, and there you can hide your `progressBarDialog`.

**You can include this code as well:**

```
public class information extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
    {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            this.cancel(true);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "asynctack cancelled.....", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            dialog.hide(); /*hide the progressbar dialog here...*/
            super.onCancelled();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Most of the time that I use AsyncTask my business logic is on a separated business class instead of being on the UI. In that case, I couldn't have a loop at doInBackground(). An example would be a synchronization process that consumes services and persist data one after another.

I end up handing on my task to the business object so it can handle cancelation. My setup is like this:

```
public abstract class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private Task mTask;
    private Business mBusiness;

    public void startTask() {
        if (mTask != null) {
            mTask.cancel(true);
        }
        mTask = new mTask();
        mTask.execute();
    }
}

protected class Task extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        super.onCancelled();

        mTask.cancel(true);

        // ask if user wants to try again
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return mBusiness.synchronize(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        mTask = null;

        if (result) {
            // done!
        }
        else {
            // ask if user wants to try again
        }
    }
}

public class Business {
    public boolean synchronize(AsyncTask<?, ?, ?> task) {
        boolean response = false;
        response = loadStuff(task);

        if (response)
            response = loadMoreStuff(task);

        return response;
    }

    private boolean loadStuff(AsyncTask<?, ?, ?> task) {
        if (task != null && task.isCancelled()) return false;

        // load stuff

        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem - essentially I was getting a NPE in an async task after the user had destroyed the activity. After researching the problem on Stack Overflow, I adopted the following solution:

```
volatile boolean running;

public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    running=true;
    ...
    }


public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    running=false;
    ...
}
```

Then, I check "if running" periodically in my async code. I have stress tested this and I am now unable to "break" my activity. This works perfectly and has the advantage of being simpler than some of the solutions I have seen on SO.

Answer (score 2):

You can just ask for cancellation but not really terminate it. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6023350/android-asynctask-blocks-back-key-dispatch-event/6023453#6023453).

Answer (score 1):

**How to cancel AsyncTask**

Full answer is here - [Android AsyncTask Example](https://androidride.com/asynctask-android-tutorial-example/#onCancelled)

AsyncTask provides a better cancellation strategy, to terminate currently running task.

**cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfitRunning)**

myTask.cancel(false)- It makes isCancelled returns true. Helps to cancel the task.

myTask.cancel(true) – It also makes isCancelled() returns true, interrupt the background thread and relieves resources .

It is considered as an arrogant way, If there is any thread.sleep() method performing in background thread, cancel(true) will interrupt background thread at that time. But cancel(false) will wait for it and cancel task when that method completes.

If you invoke cancel() and doInBackground() hasn’t begun execute yet. onCancelled() will invoke.

After invoking cancel(…) you should check value returned by isCancelled() on doInbackground() periodically. just like shown below.

```
protected Object doInBackground(Params… params)  { 
 while (condition)
{
 ...
if (isCancelled()) 
break;
}
return null; 
}
```