# how to stop asnchrounous task when click cancel button

Tags: android

i am importing contacts in to a file using asynchronous task it is going well but after starting asynchronous task if i want to cancel it on middle then how to stop it means which have been done before stooping async task should be null and stop the asynch task..my code is below pls help me..

Comment: try this `new asynctask().cancel(mayInterruptIfRunning);`

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735102/ideal-way-to-cancel-an-executing-asynctask and also this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039158/android-cancel-async-task

Comment: and in above they have used while condition for continuously fetching data one bye one..so when the boolen var is true they stops the loop and comes out of the doInBackground.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A task can be cancelled at any time by invoking **cancel(boolean)**. Invoking this method will cause subsequent calls to `isCancelled() to return true`. After invoking this method, `onCancelled(Object)`, instead of `onPostExecute(Object)` will be invoked after `doInBackground(Object[])`  returns. To ensure that a task is cancelled as quickly as possible, you should always check the return value of `isCancelled()` periodically from `doInBackground(Object[])`, **if possible (inside a loop for instance.)**

Comment: hi..i am using.  cancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {
             boolean mayInterruptIfRunning = true;
    new createCSV().cancel(mayInterruptIfRunning);
   
    
             }
           }); and in do in back ground i use    while (isCancelled()) {
                if (isCancelled())
                             {
                           Log.i("#################","true value");

                             break;
                             }
                
            }
    return null;
    } but not working..:(

Comment: cancel is the object of button ,on click cancel button i want to stop async task and why the problem is on new createCSV().cancel(mayInterruptIfRunning); i m not getting..

Comment: In your activity's onCreate() initialize AsyncTask class's object and use the same object for execute and for cancel() have you got it..?

Comment: AsyncTask<String, Void, String> createCSV = new AsyncTask<String, Void, String>() {
} like this, and in your activity use createCSV.execute() and on cancelButton just createCSV.cancel(mayInterruptIfRunning);

Answer (score 1):

Override the method `onCancelled()` and in that set flag `canceled = true;` 
and pass this canceled variable to condition in `doInBackground`.

Comment: But onCancelled()  isn't called until doInBackground has finished.

Answer (score 1):

I would have 
    while(!iscancelled()) 
as the while condition. So when your cancel button is pressed, call cancel(true) on your AsyncTask. This will cause the while condition to be false. doInBackground will then exit.

If you implementation onCancel this will be called after doInBackground and you can set the contacts to null.

Hope that helps.