# How to cancel a Async Task in android?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, contacts

Hi in my app there is an Async Task  to read contact detail(which take a little bit time).It does well , but what the problem is when i cancel the Async Task before it completes,fetching details my app get crash.So i was think that make the app to exit when i cancel the Async Task.I search the web and find some method but it did not worked,so how can i exit my app when cancelling  an async task?
**My Asyn Task   code(normal code)**

```
public class FetchingContact extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(
            MobiMailActivity.this);

    // can use UI thread here
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        this.dialog.setMessage("Fetching Contact...");
        this.dialog.show();
    }

    // automatically done on worker thread (separate from UI thread)
    protected Void doInBackground(final String... args) {
        readContact();
        if (isCancelled ()) {

            finish();
        }

        return null;
    }

    // can use UI thread here
    protected void onPostExecute(final Void unused) {
        if (this.dialog.isShowing()) {
            this.dialog.dismiss();
            CharSequence test=sam;
            //  search_sort.setText(test);
                check(test);


        }
        // reset the output view by retrieving the new data
        // (note, this is a naive example, in the real world it might make
        // sense
        // to have a cache of the data and just append to what is already
        // there, or such
        // in order to cut down on expensive database operations)
        // new SelectDataTask().execute();
    }

}
```

Comment: no error while loading asy task but when canel that  task makes crash its is due the in completion of that task.My question is how to exit app when canel a asyn task

Comment: What u r doing to exit the app on cancel is correct it seems but my concern is when u finish the activity, progressDialog is still active. So logcat message shows exact reason for crash

Comment: Here is my answer for: [**Android: Cancel Async Task**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6053943/379693)

Comment: perfect got it post you answer so that i can accept it @Paresh Mayani

Comment: @Ramz sorry i can't and i dont want :) (SO Rule)

Comment: Please follow the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7734109/6736510)

Answer (score 1):

A `AsyncTask` can be cancelled at any time by invoking `cancel(boolean)`. Invoking this method will cause subsequent calls to `isCancelled()` to return true. After invoking this method, `onCancelled(Object)`, instead of `onPostExecute(Object)` will be invoked after `doInBackground(Object[])` returns. **To ensure that a task is cancelled as quickly as possible, you should always check the return value of isCancelled() periodically from doInBackground(Object[]), if possible (inside a loop for instance.)**

This is literally quoted from the [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). But seeing as you have put your entire code in a method called readContact(), you can't do this.

What you could do is this:

```
protected void onPostExecute(final Void unused) {
    if (this.dialog.isShowing()) {
        this.dialog.dismiss();
        (if !isCancelled()) {
            CharSequence test=sam;
        //  search_sort.setText(test);
            check(test);
        }
    }
}
```

So you check at the end of your AsyncTask if something should be done. This is not the way to do it, so I suggest you take your `readContact()` method, and put it entirely in the AsyncTask, or if it's a method inside your AsyncTask, call `isCancelled()` check in there.

Comment: but how i exit from my app on cancel.i think i cancel my app during readContact(); in do in back ground

Answer (score 0):

1. I assume you try to get the result by calling `get()` method, that throws exception when the task is cancelled. How about checking [`isCancelled()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#isCancelled%28%29) before you try to retrieve the result?

   `if(!task.isCancelled()) { 
    Result result = task.get();
   }`
2. Also, you might try to check out [`onCancelled()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onCancelled%28Result%29). This runs on the UI thread, and will be called when the task is cancelled.