# how can i kill other tasks when i click on new button?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, hessian

I'm developing an android application, so i have a nice GUI with many buttons. Every one when clicked, declenche w new task to load data from distant server (for that i'm using Hessian). for more detail: supposing we have two buttons:

1. the first one for loading Events and the other for doing something else.
2. when i click on the first one and before the load is complete, i clicked on the other button.
3. at that time i want to annulate the first task(i'm using AsyncTask) and start the second.
   How can i do it?

Comment: You can cancel the first task and can start second task immediately. check: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6053943/379693

Comment: i have many tasks and when i declanche a new one i don't know what's the task already running.