# How to cancel AsyncTask in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I have created an Android Application, in that I want to cancel AsyncTask onPause state of Fragment.

I tried using `AsyncTask.cancel(true);` but it gives null pointer exception.

```
@Override
public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    AsyncTask.cancel(true);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: you need object of AsyncTask instead of AsyncTask class, see this for more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039158/android-cancel-async-task

Comment: I have created the object of it, but still gives null pointer error.

Comment: check object, maybe you not initialized that, check if it's not null then cancel tht

Comment: correct and safe way to cancel an asynctask http://www.quicktips.in/correct-way-to-cancel-an-asynctask-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

`task.cancel()` will do it. Be sure to include frequent checks to `isCancelled()` in your `onBackground()` as well as in `onPostExecute()` to avoid accessing/updating UI which is no longer there.

```
public void onActivityPause() {
    task.cancel();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

asyncTask.cancel(true); will change a boolean value only and don't stop your thread.
so you need to "ask" if the async task not cancelled.

example:

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    while(!isCancelled()){
        // do something
    }
    return null;
}
```