# How to really cancel Async task?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have progressDialog, which is used for my AsyncTask, while downloading file. In AsyncTask I have implemented theese methods:

```
@Override
protected void onCancelled() {
  handleOnCancelled(this.result);
  super.onCancelled();
}


@Override
protected void onCancelled(String result) {
    super.onCancelled(result);

}
```

In my activty, I am declaring mProgressDialog and giving it onCancelListener:

```
mProgressDialog.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
       xml.cancel(true);


    }
});
```

When I press back key, mProgressDialog is closed, onCancel (method above) is called, but Async Task still runs on the background. How to solve it?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039158/android-cancel-async-task

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to repeatedly check the boolean `isCanceled()` within your `doInBackground()` method. If this method returns true, you should immediately exit any loop or background work being done by the task.

Refer to the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
if(myAsyncTask.getStatus().equals(AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING))
{    
      myAsyncTask.cancel(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for `isCanceled()` in the async task while you are downloading.