# How to cancel or stop AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have found many answers to cancel an AsyncTask, to set object.cancel(true)
and in do in background method check

```
for (int i = 0; i < appState.getAvailableText().length;i++){

  if(isCancelled()){
                break;
            }
            //Do your updating stuff here
        }
```

But in my Asynctask there is no for loops or switch cases ,hw can i Stop or Cancel the AsyncTYask background process by clicking a button???

Comment: keep an active object of async task ... when ever you want to cancel just call cancel true ...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: Cancel Async Task](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039158/android-cancel-async-task)

Comment: Try it using `AsyncTask.cancel(true)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your button click write the code

`task.cancel(true);`

where `task` is the reference of the async task you have created and started

Comment: No, it would be `cancel(boolean)`. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel(boolean)