# Cancelling all the running instances of an AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Is there anyway to cancel all the running instances of an Asynctask ? Thanks in advance.

I want to cancel the progress dialog on pressing back button meanwhile all the instances of an asynctask from the same piece of code.

Comment: Call the `cancel` method. Refer to this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel(boolean)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Cancel Async Task](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039158/android-cancel-async-task)

Comment: You can't cancel all instances WITHOUT a reference to EACH individual AsyncTask. Read docs on what cancel() does form AsyncTask.

Comment: Actually there are different instances of the same asyncTask and i want to cancel all of them from the same event

Comment: @Sree its not the duplicate please try to understand this it is different case

Comment: @JoxTraex okk thanks , so i have to track all the instances of the asynctask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't cancel all instances **WITHOUT** a reference to **EACH** individual AsyncTask.

Read docs on what cancel() does form AsyncTask.

Once you have a reference to each AsyncTask, then you can cancel each of them.

Answer (score 2):

use following code to cancel  running asynctask

```
if(myAsyncTask.getStatus().equals(AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING))
  {
 myAsyncTask.cancel(true);
 }
```

Comment: this answer already exists please understand the problem statement

Answer (score 2):

I could solve it making a flag in OnStop()

1- Declare a global

```
    int flagOnStop=0;
```

2- Declare all global AsyncTask -->

```
    Async_Task asyncTask1,asyncTask2,asyncTaskn;
```

3- Before execute it, ask for flagOnStop -->

```
if(flagOnStop==0{
    asyncTask1=new Async_Task();
    asyncTask1.execute();

    asyncTask2=new Async_Task();
    asyncTask2.execute();

    asyncTaskn=new Async_Task();
    asyncTaskn.execute();

}
```

4- When your activity stop make the flag equals to one

```
@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    flagOnStop=1;
    asyncTask.cancel();
    asyncTask2.cancel();
    asyncTaskn.cancel();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a boolean flag in your activity (or wherever visible to the asynctasks) and inside the asynctask do:

```
while (flag) {
    your_logic;
}
```

When pressing back set the flag to false and every asynctask should stop itself - then you don't need a reference to the asyntasks themselves because they will do all the work.

Answer (score 0):

**FOUND THE SOLUTION:** I added an action listener before uploadingDialog.show() like this:

```
uploadingDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener(){
      public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
          myTask.cancel(true);
          //finish();
      }
});
```

That way when I press the back button, the above OnCancelListener cancels both dialog and task. Also you can add finish() if you want to finish the whole activity on back pressed. Remember to declare your async task as a variable like this:

```
MyAsyncTask myTask=null;
```

and execute your async task like this:

```
myTask = new MyAsyncTask();
myTask.execute();
```

Reference : [Android: Cancel Async Task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039158/android-cancel-async-task)

Comment: This is not geared towards his question. He wasn't asking how do you cancel one AsyncTask, he was asking about how you cancel several. Please refer to my post.