# doInBackground is not getting called

Tags: java, android

If any internal threads are going on in the doInBackground and it takes more time for the response to come back, and in the mean while if again I call the same async task, how to kill the previous threads in the doInBckground and run the new one?can anyone please help me?Thanks in advance.

Comment: `internal threads are going on in the doInBackground` ?? internal threads in doInBackgroud? You should not use threads there.

Comment: please add the code what you have tried.

Comment: `doInBackground is not getting called`. There is nothing in your post about this problem.

Comment: show your code please

Comment: visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039158/android-cancel-async-task

Answer (score 1):

According to Google you can't call the same asynctask object twice. If you do so it will throw an exception.

> The task can be executed only once (an exception will be thrown if a second execution is attempted.)

For details see the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). Read 'Threading rules' chapter.

As @greenapps said, don't use any thread inside `doInBackground`. `doInBackground` itself running under a thread.

If you want to cancel the previous asynctask that is currently running call `cancel(true)` method of asynctask object. If you rerun the task, then reinitialize that object and execute it again.