# Google Play services Task API: can a Task be cancelled

Tags: android, firebase

When use [Tasks.call(Callable)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Tasks.html#call(java.util.concurrent.Callable<TResult>)), can I cancel it, and remove all the listeners from the task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need a way to remove all the listeners from any Task at any time, you will have to remember all the listeners you previously added, then remove them all manually.

If you're working with an Android app, and you add [Activity-scoped listeners](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/tasks#activity-scoped_listeners), they will be removed automatically when the host activity is stopped (goes through its `onStop()` lifecycle method).  Note that you have to pass the activity as an argument to `addOnCompleteListener()`.

Comment: Thank you for your replay. I was hoping there might be an easy way to cancel a Task without override CancellableTask, since overriding CancellableTask, I won't be able to use Tasks.call().

Comment: @Doug Stevenson Can you elaborate how exactly one can remove the listeners? I cannot see an API for that and addXXXListener on a task does not accept `null`.  Moreover I am looking a way to Cancel a task but it appears that the APIs are precisely build to prevent that. It make using Task prone to leaking activities. I understand that there are "Activity-scoped listeners" but there are many scenarios where this is not sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

A [`Task`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task) class doesn't have a function you can call to cancel. You should use it's subclass [`CancellableTask`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/storage/CancellableTask) instead, to be able to use [`cancel()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/storage/CancellableTask.html#cancel()):

> public abstract boolean **cancel ()**
>
> Attempts to cancel the task. A canceled task cannot be resumed later. A canceled task calls back on listeners subscribed to [`addOnFailureListener(OnFailureListener)`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task.html#addOnFailureListener(com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener)) with an exception that indicates the task was canceled.
>
> **Returns**
>
> - true if this task was successfully canceled or is in the process of being canceled. Returns false if the task is already completed or in a state that cannot be canceled.

If you still insist on using `Task` instead, I think it'd be best to refer to similar posts that are using `AsyncTask`s like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6039158/4625829).