# AsyncTask still operating after the method (.cancel)

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

AsyncTask still runs after calling the method new myTask.cancel(). I call the method when i press the back button, or when i change the fragment with a spinner. I have logged the progress of increments, and even after the myTask.cancel is called, the increments still rises.

My AsyncTask class

```
 public class myTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {
        private static final String TAG = "myTask";
        private ProgressBar budgetProgressBar=null;
        private TextView textView1;
        double b_val,e_val;
        int position;
        private Context mContext;

        public myTask(){
        }


        public myTask(double b_val ,double e_val,ProgressBar budgetProgressBar, TextView textView1) {
            this.b_val = b_val;
            this.textView1=textView1;
            this.e_val = e_val;
            pStatus = (int) e_val;
            this.budgetProgressBar= budgetProgressBar;
            position = (int) budgetProgressBar.getTag();
            maxBudget = (int) this.b_val;
        }


        int pStatus;
        int maxBudget;


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            budgetProgressBar.setMax(maxBudget);
            budgetProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

               budgetProgressBar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
    //        }
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

            int incrementor =10;


                for (int i = incrementor; i<=pStatus && !isCancelled(); i+=incrementor){

                    if (isCancelled()){
                        Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: CANCELLED");
                        break;
                    }

                    try {

                        Thread.sleep(10);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    publishProgress(i);
                }


            return "Complete";
        }


        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... p) {

            super.onProgressUpdate(p);
            Log.d(TAG, "onProgressUpdate: ");
            if ((int) budgetProgressBar.getTag() == position){
                budgetProgressBar.incrementProgressBy(p[0]);
                budgetProgressBar.setProgress(p[0]);
                textView1.setText(p[0]+"/"+maxBudget);
               // Log.d(TAG, "Setting progress to " + p[0]);

                double calc =(e_val/b_val)*100;
                if (calc>100){
                    calc-=100;
                    textView1.setText("-"+ ((int) calc)+"%");
                }else{
                    textView1.setText(((int) calc)+"%");
                }

            }

        }





    }
```

Cancelling the AsyncTask

```
new myTask().cancel(true);
```

Comment: Might help you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/6053943/423980

Comment: I assume you don't cancel it via `new myTask().cancel(true);` though, but instead cancel the running instance.

Answer (score 4):

The `AsyncTask#cancel` does not stop the `doInBackground` task even if the method name suggests it as that. What happens is that `doInBackground` will run until the end and it will call `onCancel` instead of `onPostExecute` in the end.

So you might want to add a volatile field flag to `AsyncTask` and set that as cancelled for example

```
AsyncTask
private volatile boolean isRunning = true;

public void cancelTask() // sets isRunning to false
```

And you would check for `isRunning` instead of `isCancelled()`.

Comment: so the 'doInBackground' task cannot be stopped programmatically, when it is running?

Comment: @Fritz_Playmaker It can. See the second part of my answer and replace your current `if (isCancelled())` with `if (isRunning)`

Answer (score 1):

please read this document for better understand of AsyncTask in Android 
 https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html