# Abort AsyncTask repeat when finish bind data

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm using AsyncTask for fill data in textViews, images, other views with soap object.
but when I change Orientation to landscape the AsyncTask repeat the process and show Facebook shimmer again.
how to stop AsynkTask when fetching my data is done?

Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
TextView helloTxt;
RelativeLayout rel;
boolean done = false;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    helloTxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.helloTxt);
    rel = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rel);
    // call the inner Class from here

    new callSoapObject().execute();

}
```

This is AsyncTask Inner Class :

```
private class callSoapObject extends AsyncTask<String,Object,String>{
    private final String NameSpace = "https://tempuri.org/";
    private final String URL = "https://192.168.0.102/Service.svc/soap";
    final String Method_Name = "DoWork";
    final String SOAP_ACTION = "https://tempuri.org/IService/DoWork";
    public int TimeOut = 5000;
    String response;
    ShimmerFrameLayout container;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        //Start Progress bar or placeHolder
        container = (ShimmerFrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.shimmer_view_container);
        container.startShimmerAnimation();
    }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        // create SoapObj
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NameSpace, Method_Name);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope Envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        Envelope.dotNet = true;
        Envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE transportSE = new HttpTransportSE(URL, TimeOut);
        try {
            transportSE.call(SOAP_ACTION, Envelope);
            response = (String) Envelope.getResponse();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("Error", e.toString());
        }
        return response;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // stop progressBar
        container.stopShimmerAnimation();
        if (result != null) {
            helloTxt.setText(result);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            rel.setBackgroundResource(0);
            rel.setMinimumWidth(helloTxt.getWidth());
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Cancel Async Task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039158/android-cancel-async-task)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to handle orientation change with background task, then I think you can use AsyncTaskLoader instead of AsyncTask.
AsyncTaskLoader will handle orientation change for you.

[Here](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/01/android-loaders-versus-asynctask.html) you can find differences between AsyncTask and AsyncTaskLoader!

[Here](https://medium.com/@sanjeevy133/an-idiots-guide-to-android-asynctaskloader-76f8bfb0a0c0) you can find AsyncTaskLoader Tutorial

[Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html) is the official documentation of AsyncTaskLoader

Comment: Yeah I know, so that's why I'm suggesting you use AsyncTaskLoader to fetch data, so even if you rotate your device your data won't disappear!

Comment: Read articles I've provided there you'll get the difference!

Answer (score 0):

As it seems to me that you don't want to use a different layout and resources when orientation changes, you can prevent this problem by avoiding destroy and recreate of your activity by adding below configuration to your `AndroidManifest` file:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"/>
```

[Here](https://android.jlelse.eu/handling-orientation-changes-in-android-7072958c442a) you can find other solution for handling orientation change.