# Pause AsyncTask before going to other activity

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an activity which downloads images in background in a listView using AsyncTask,
when i press an item in that list i go to another activity.
Even when i have moved to second activity the asynctask keeps on downloading the images.
How to i pause it.

Also can you please tell me how to pause this downloading process.

Comment: AsyncTask cannot be paused/resumed once it started, however, it can be cancelled/restarted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't really pause an AsyncTask. You can, however, complete the AsyncTask and then store the progress, once you are back to the original Activity, you can resume the loading of Images (based on the stored progress)

Comment: Also see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735102/ideal-way-to-cancel-an-executing-asynctask) for designing AsyncTasks