# How to dismiss dialog while doInBackground is running in asynctask?

Tags: android

I am trying to cancel a dialog from the mainthread while the 'doInBackGround' method of AsyncTask is running. While I am downloading a photo, a progress dialog pops up and when it is finished downloading I dismis() the dialog in onPostExecute. If the connection is slow, the dialog is up for a while and I cannot cancel it until there is a timeout error or it finishes downloading. How do I use the back-button so the main thread can access. Here is what my code looks like:

```
private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {


    protected void onPreExecute() {
        //this piece code doesn't seem to work
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "",
                "Image loading", true);
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        //bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        someMethod(result);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a cancellable progress dialog, pass in a cancel listener to the progress dialog and cancel the task within that method, eg

```
protected void onPreExecute() {
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(activity, "Searching files", "Scanning...", true, true,
            new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    // When dialog in cancelled, need to explicitly cancel task otherwise it keeps on running
                    cancel(true);
                }
            }
    );

    progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can intercept the `onBackKeyPressed` event, and cancel the task using `cancel` method.

See that link:
[Ideal way to cancel an executing AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735102/ideal-way-to-cancel-an-executing-asynctask)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a `ProgressDialog` which is `cancelable`. This is the signature of the method:-

```
public static ProgressDialog show (Context context, CharSequence title, CharSequence message, boolean indeterminate, boolean cancelable)
```