# Halt AsyncTask execution, prompt for user input and continue execution based on user input

Tags: android

I have the following `AsyncTask`

```
public class LoadFromCloudTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Boolean> {

    public LoadFromCloudTask(LoadFromCloudTaskFragment loadFromCloudTaskFragment) {
        this.loadFromCloudTaskFragment = loadFromCloudTaskFragment;
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ...
        ...
        ...
        // How possible I can halt my execution, prompt for user input, and continue execution based on user input.
        // In Swing, I can ...
        //
        /*
           // Hold the execution, and prompt for user input
           final int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(LoadFromCloudJDialog.this, message, MessagesBundle.getString("question_title_overwrite_your_data_by_cloud_data_at"), JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
           // Continue execution based on user input.
         */
    }
}
```

I was wondering, is it possible to halt AsyncTask execution, prompt for user input and continue execution based on user input?

In Swing, I can achieve this by simply using `JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog`. How about Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `doInBackground` executes in a different thread, you'll have to pause this thread while showing some [dialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) in the UI Thread, and once the dialog dismisses you can resume the `AsyncTask` and read the result.

Answer (score 1):

Check documentation of the [Asynctask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) , you can cancel and restart the async task, because `The task can be executed only once`

May you want something like this [ideal-way-to-cancel-an-executing-asynctask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735102/ideal-way-to-cancel-an-executing-asynctask)

**doInBackground not execute in UI thread, so you can perform UI operation of showing dialog**

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by sending messages to **UIThread** using `publishProgress` from inside `doInBackground(Params...)` and use java's **wait/notify** mechanisem to wait untel the user enters his input.

A psudo code would look something like this:

```
 public Object mLock = new Object();
 protected void doInBackground(Params... params){
  /// do your requests.
  publishProgress(Progress ...progress);
  mLock.wait();

 }
 protected void onProgressUpdate(Progress ....progress) {
    // request user input here
 }
```

and from your UIThread just call `mLock.notify()` to ask the code  to continue.

Also you can perform slimier behavior by splitting your logic across multiple AsynchTasks it will not be very costly because AsynchTasks are managed by a shared (static) ThreadPoolExecutor and a

Answer (score 1):

```
You can create pause and resume method inside asyntask as below, and call it according to your convenience.

        public class LoadFromCloudTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Boolean> {

            public LoadFromCloudTask(LoadFromCloudTaskFragment loadFromCloudTaskFragment) {
                this.loadFromCloudTaskFragment = loadFromCloudTaskFragment;
            }

    //call this when you want to halt the task        
                    public void pause() {
                           if (this.getStatus().equals(Status.RUNNING)) {
                                   try {
                                           this.wait();
                                   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                           e.printStackTrace();
                                   }
                           }
                   }

    // call this when you need to resume the task
                   public void resume() {
                           if (this.getStatus().equals(Status.PENDING)) {
                                   this.notify();
                           }
                   }

            @Override
            protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
                ...
                ...
                ...
                // How possible I can halt my execution, prompt for user input, and continue execution based on user input.
                // In Swing, I can ...
                //
                /*
                   // Hold the execution, and prompt for user input
                   final int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(LoadFromCloudJDialog.this, message, MessagesBundle.getString("question_title_overwrite_your_data_by_cloud_data_at"), JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                   // Continue execution based on user input.
                 */
            }
        }
```

Comment: Had high hopes for this approach, but didn't work. Crashes on the pause(). :(