# Cancel AsyncTask after some time

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

This could be a duplicate question but I did not find what I was looking for.
I am calling an AsyncTask in the UI activity  `new LoadData().execute();` and in doInBackground I call a method which takes time. I want to interrupt this thread if the data is not return after some time.
Below is the code how I tried to do this.

```
class LoadData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
    protected String doInBackground(String... args)
    {

        DataCollector dc = new DataCollector();
        data = dc.collectData(query);
        //Here I check if the time is greater than 30 seconds then cancel
        if(((System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime)/1000)>30)
        {
           cancel(true);
        }
    return null;
    }
}
```

But this does not stop the task after 30 seconds, in fact it is taking more time.
I have tried `get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit);` as well but that does not work either.

Can anyone show me how can I do it or how do I use isCancelled() in doInBackground.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this answer helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11191070/3307066.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need a thread that cancels your task after a certain amount of time. That Thread could look like this:

```
public class TaskCanceler implements Runnable{
    private AsyncTask task;

    public TaskCanceler(AsyncTask task) {
        this.task = task;
    }

     @Override
     public void run() {
        if (task.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING )
            task.cancel(true);
     }
}
```

And when you call your AsyncTask, you need to run the cancle task after a certain amount of time (=the timeout, in this case 20 sec)

```
private Handler handler = new Handler();
private TaskCanceler taskCanceler;
...
LoadData task = new LoadData();
taskCanceler = new TaskCanceler(task);
handler.postDelayed(taskCanceler, 20*1000);
task.execute(...)
```

It's a good idea if you clean this up on cancel or finish with

```
if(taskCanceler != null && handler != null) {
     handler.removeCallbacks(taskCanceler);
}
```

You can of course wrap this in an custom implementation of AsyncTask. I've used this pattern many times and it works like a charm. One thing to note, in rare cases the handler would not start, I suspect if you create it in the wrong context it will not survive in certain instances, so I forced the handler to be an the UI Thread with `handler= new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());`

Answer (score 3):

You have to do the Time check on a different thread.

What you currently do is: executing the `dc.collectData(query)` (in background) and once it is ready you check if you should cancel. So if the query takes 1 minute, you will do the cancel check after 1 minute, which is already too late.

What you could do is schedule a TimerTask that should run 30 seconds after the LoadData().execute() and if the timer Task is run, you can cancel the AsyncTask (if it is still running)

Answer (score 2):

I would translate this into an async/await problem making all the expensive methods as async methods.

First, Modify DataCollector's collectData(query) to collectDataAsync(query). (If you can't modify DataCollector, there are work arounds to wrap it in a lambda function or something similar).

Second, change doInBackground as an async task, something like this:

```
protected async Task<String> doInBackgroundAsync(String... args)
{
    DataCollector dc = new DataCollector();
    int timeout = 1000;
    var task = dc.collectDataAsync(query);
    if (await Task.WhenAny(task, Task.Delay(timeout)) == task) {
        // task completed within timeout
        data = task.Result;
    } else { 
        // timeout logic
    }
}
```

Basically, you have two tasks inside doInBackgroundAsync: collectDataAsync and a delay task.
Your code waits for the faster one. Then you know which one was and you can react accordingly.

If you also need to cancel collectDataAsync task, then you want to used a cancellationToken.
I use this to solve your problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/11191070/3307066.

Note that now doInBackgroundAsync is a async, so it changes a bit the way of using it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: If you think this question is a duplicate you should flag as a duplicate, instead of posting a link to another question.

Comment: I modified my answer. I don't think is a duplicate, hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is you CAN'T cancel an AsyncTask once its started. What you can do, is insert a loop inside `doInBackGround()` which will check for `isCancelled()` and if it is set to true sometime in the future - return a value from the function (which will in turn call `onPostExecute()` if you have defined it);

Note that just because you can't stop an AsyncTask doesn't mean that the OS won't cancel it if it's low on memory. You should have this in mind if you are doing essential tasks in the AsyncTask (ones that you want executed 100%). If so, it is better to use a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) - a component that is automatically killed and restarted by the OS as need.

Comment: Actually I am collecting data from external sensors over the socket connections sometimes because of connection problem or if the sensor is offline, this process can take a long, that is why I want to interrupt the task. You say it cannot be cancelled then why do we have `cancel(boolean state); get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit);` methods avaiable?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private volatile boolean running = true;
    private final ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    public MyTask(Context ctx) {
        progressDialog = gimmeOne(ctx);

        progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
        progressDialog.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                // actually could set running = false; right here, but I'll
                // stick to contract.
                cancel(true);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        running = false;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        while (running) {
            // does the hard work
        }
        return null;
    }

    // ...

}
```

[Courtesy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735102/ideal-way-to-cancel-an-executing-asynctask) and for more details see this answer.

Comment: this is correct, but it will allow the user to always cancel the job and will not automatically cancel it after 30 seconds

Comment: you can use a timer inside do in background ,set some time say 30 seconds and after that post cancel() ..it will stop your asynctask at any point

Comment: @Shruti: Thanks for the reference but I don't want to allow users to cancel the operation. And `cancel(true)` does not seem to work for me. How can I use `get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit);` becuase is sounds more feasible.