# How to stop Asynctask from Timer?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to stop Asynctask from Timer but it is not stopping.
Here is code where I schedule the `timerTask(asynctask)`

```
public void CreateTimer(){
    timer =new Timer();
    timerTask = new MyTimertask();
    timer.schedule(timerTask,5000,2000);
}
```

Comment: did you get any error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cancel AsyncTask after some time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17315372/cancel-asynctask-after-some-time)

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html) for `TimerTask` doesn't seem to have the schedule method. You can cancel an AsyncTask with `cancel(true)`.
Maybe instead you could use a [CountdownTimer](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html) or a new [Thread](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html)?

With `CountdownTimer`:

```
CountDownTimer cdt = new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long l) {}

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            cancel();//Cancel CountdownTimer
            cancel(true);// Cancel Asynctask
        }
    };
    cdt.start();
```

With `Thread`:

```
Thread thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                super.run();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                    cancel(true);//Cancel Asynctask
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
            }
        };
thread.start();
```

Answer (score -1):

Async task can be cancelled at any time by invoking `cancel(boolean).` More information can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

It would be helpful if you post your code to give a more precise answer.