# cancelling a progressdialog while in operation

Tags: android

I have an Activity class inside which i have an class which extends ASynctask class where i perform parsing...everything works fine...In preexecute method of Asynctask i have set progress dialog cancellability to false through

```
 dialog.setCancelable(false);
```

which works fine..
Now i want that if user presses Hardware back button then the that progressdialog along with loading of data should get canceled and goes back to previous activity...
How can i do so?? plz help..

Answer (score 0):

> Now i want that if user presses Hardware back button then the that
>   progressdialog along with loading of data should get canceled and goes
>   back to previous activity... How can i do so??

You need to enable canceling and then override `onCancelled()` method. And there, just create new `Intent` that moves to previous Activity (or to whatever you want).

```
@Override
protected void onCancelled() {
   // do your stuff
}
```

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735102/ideal-way-to-cancel-an-executing-asynctask). It's useful example and a point you can start.

Comment: where should i call and define this method?? in asynctask class or in Activity class?? @sajmon

Comment: @Keshri_raj in `AsyncTask` subclass.

Comment: you need not call that its another method just like pre execute

Comment: OnCancelled() method is not showing in my asynctask class.. what to do..??

Comment: @Keshri_raj you need to override it. Just copy and paste my code.

Comment: Sorry @Sajmon it didnt worked :(..bt thnx fr hlp....still stuck up with the prblm..