# Android: Can not cancel an Async Task

Tags: android, android-asynctask, androidhttpclient, asynchttpclient

I have an `Activity` A which has a button. Up on tapping on the button, it opens up another `Activity` B, which displays data fetched from server (http). The `API` version that I am using is 15.

As soon as the `Activity` B is opened, in `onCreate()` method, I am calling following lines of code.

```
        asyncFetch = new AsyncFetch();
        asyncFetch.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
```

This `Async` task performs `http` communication to fetch data from server.

```
    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
        ...
        defaultHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        httpPost = new HttpPost(theURL);
        ...
        HttpResponse response = defaultHttpClient.execute(httpPost);
        ...
        return response...;
    }
```

Once data is fetched, the UI is populated.

`onBackPressed()` and `home` button, I am calling the following code to cancel the `Async` task.

```
            asyncFetch.cancel(true);
```

When a back button or home button is tapped, the `Async` task is not getting cancelled and UI waits for the Async task to complete and then it goes back to parent Activity.

The reason of not using the `execute()` is because I have couple of `Async` tasks that are running which I don't want this task to wait for other `Async` task to complete.

Can someone tell me how to cancel this Async task? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: AsyncTasks, are something I am seeing being used less and less. They have problems staying with the Activity life cycle. I would suggest Volley (which is very good) or using an IntentService as these do not get so involved with the life cycle.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735102/ideal-way-to-cancel-an-executing-asynctask

Comment: To add to @SergeyBenner s comment, look at the second answer specifically

Answer (score 1):

if you are using this

```
asyncFetch.cancel(true);
```

Then you need to check in `doInBackGround()` method that does user set cancel to `true` . There is a method define in `asyntask` , `isCancelled()`.you need to check it like.

```
if(isCancelled())
//break out of doInBackground and handle this case
```

Android documentation says about `isCancelled()`.

> Returns true if this task was cancelled before it completed normally.
>   If you are calling cancel(boolean) on the task, the value returned by
>   this method should be checked periodically from
>   doInBackground(Object[]) to end the task as soon as possible.

you can check documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#isCancelled%28%29) too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your  `doInBackgraopund()` method like this:

```
 @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {

       if (isCancelled()) {   // Always check for satus of your AsnycTask sataus. if it cancel break from loop.

          break;  // As long as your AsyncTask has cancel it will stop processing

       }
       else {
         // do your work here
      }

}
```