# Unable to cancel Async task on button click

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am trying to cancel/end an async task on the button click of a pop-up box. However, when I click on the button the onCancelled() method is not being called. Could someone please help me with this? Below is my code:

```
public AuthenticationAsync(Context context, final String rid) {
    this.rid = rid;

    alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("Information");
    alertDialog.setMessage("RaspberryPi Validated");
    alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    cancel(true); //Cancelling async task on button click
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
}


@Override
protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
    String metricData = String.valueOf(kuraPayload.getMetric("data"));
    if (metricData.isEmpty()) 
        subResponse = false;
}

@Override
protected void onCancelled() {
    Log.d("Async","cancelled");  //not being called
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
    if (subResponse) {
        asyncHttpClient = new AsyncHttpClient();
        asyncHttpClient.get(WSConstants.ADD_RPI_WS + MQTTFactory.getRaspberryPiById(), new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
                Toast.makeText(ActivityContexts.getMainActivityContext(), "RaspberryPi Validated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                alertDialog.show();
            }

    } 
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the it's never getting into `onCancelled()` because you are actually calling `alertDialog.show()` in `onPostExecute()`.  Since `doInBackground()` has already completed, there is nothing to cancel.

The `cancel()` method is meant to be called during the execution of the `doInBackground()` method, which is the only method that runs on a background Thread.

Note that even if `cancel()` is called during execution of `doInBackground()`, the execution of the method won't be stopped immediately.  You should do periodic checks to `isCancelled()` and if it returns true, then exit out of the method.

After `doInBackground()` has completed, if `cancel()` has been called, then `onCancelled()` will be called instead of `onPostExecute()`.

Here is a very simple test based on your code:

```
public class AuthenticationAsync extends AsyncTask {

    AlertDialog alertDialog;
    String rid;

    public AuthenticationAsync(Context context, final String rid) {
        this.rid = rid;

        alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Information");
        alertDialog.setMessage("RaspberryPi Validated");
        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        cancel(true); //Cancelling async task on button click
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        //for testing, showing the dialog before the background Thread starts
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
       //cycle forever until the user clicks OK
       while (true){
           try {
               Thread.sleep(1000);
           } catch (InterruptedException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
           //Check if user clicked OK in the dialog
           if (isCancelled()){
               //Exit the method if the user dismissed the dialog
               return null;
           }
       }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        Log.d("Async", "cancelled");  //this is called now
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "postExecute", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

**Result:**

Dialog is shown during execution of `doInBackground()`:

[image: dialog shown]

After clicking OK, `onCancelled()` is called:

[image: onCancelled]

Answer (score 0):

@yanchenko answered something similar there -> [Ideal way to cancel an executing AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735102/ideal-way-to-cancel-an-executing-asynctask)

You can use one ProgressDialog and set this dialog as Cancelable and set the CancelListener.