# How to kill a Fragment or a Thread completely?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-fragments

I am working on an app in which i have two `Fragment`s hosted in one `Activity`. The acitivity layout has a bottom bar which has buttons that switch the two fragments.
In those fragments there are `Thread`s that do some internet work and then update their layout.

**Hieararchy:**

- `Activity`

  - `Fragment` 1

    - `Thread` 1
  - `Fragment` 2

    - `Thread` 2

**The problem**

The problem is that when, say `Thread` 1  starts doing some work, the user clicks the button to switch to `Fragment` 2, the `Thread` continues to run in the background, and when it is done with it's network task and tries to update the view (in the now not visible `Fragment` 1), the app crashes because `getActivity()` or `getContext()` now returns `null`.

**EDIT: The thread uses `getActivity()` and `getContext()` a lot, not only for updating layout, but also for saving `SharedPreferences`, etc.** **I can add an inspection (`if(!stopped)` for example) to every line that uses `Context`, but i thought there is a better way than wrapping every step in an if condition.**

So how do I kill either the `Thread` or `Fragment` completely? I don't need the background work running when the fragments are switched, I only need it to run when the fragment is visible.

I have tried both `Thread.interrupt()` and removing the fragment (instead of replacing) using `getSupportFragmentManager.remove(Fragment fragment)`. Did not work.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: So maybe check if `Fragment` is still visible or `getActivity() == null` before moving to the next part.

Comment: Are you by any chance catching the `InterruptException` inside the thread you're trying to terminate?

Comment: Ditto to what @Antonvb said, are you catching the interrupt exception and ignoring it?

Comment: Hello, i am only catching `InterruptedException` in certain parts of code where i need the thread to sleep. Eg.: `doWork;  try{Thread.sleep(500);}catch(InterruptedException e){}  doOtherWorkAfterSleeping();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may check in your thread whether `getActivity()` is null and in this case do not perform UI update. A better aprach would be to stop your download once a user switches to another fragment - how to do it depends on what HTTP client you are using. With `HttpURLConnection` it should suffice to call `disconnect()`.

Instead of using Thread consider using AsyncTask which has support for being cancelled. For examples search SO, here is one: [Ideal way to cancel an executing AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735102/ideal-way-to-cancel-an-executing-asynctask).

Comment: I would be wary of recommending AsyncTask, there are many well documented corner cases, and many better approaches, for example: http://blog.danlew.net/2014/06/21/the-hidden-pitfalls-of-asynctask/

Comment: I agree, with AsyncTask you have to be carefull when rotating screen or when holding references, etc.

Comment: Hello, thanks for advice, i don't want to use AsyncTask because i would need to check if it is canceled in every step, same problem. Please see the edit.

Comment: @FrantišekHlinka I would advice you to do the checks. You say you update UI from your thread, you must then do it inside a handler on UI thread, because otherwise you would get exceptions. So all you have to do is to add a check ie. if (getActivity == null) return; at the top of this handler. Probaby, in the end you will reproduce AsyncTask, whether you like it or not.

Comment: Why can't the download continue when the view is switched, and the UI updates be queued up for the next refresh (I would probably use a thread lock during view creation/restoration (onCreate/onResume) and do conditional view updates based on it's value or something.